# Plasma Ball and effect of Humans

Tags: plasma-physics

If one brings a fluorescent bulb  close to a plasma ball, why does the touch of a finger cause the bulb to become brighter when touched?  Why, when you hold the metal portion of the bulb, as opposed to the glass, does it NOT turn on at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram would clarify where you're holding the bulb, and which part is close to the plasma ball. (And, just what a "plasma ball" is.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom - Google Plasma ball and floursent tube. Here is an image that shows what he is talking about. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://f.tqn.com/y/chemistry/1/S/x/G/2/plasma-fluorescent.jpg&imgrefurl=http://chemistry.about.com/od/demonstrationsexperiments/ss/Plasma-Ball-And-Fluorescent-Light-Experiment.htm&h=427&w=640&tbnid=jxS6duC7sWRlvM:&docid=P0MLkY5bqegSYM&ei=Tl-cVuD9O4GtmQGK_pDIAw&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjg3KvquLLKAhWBViYKHQo_BDkQMwglKAgwCA

Comment: Here is another post very similar to your question. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56767/37364